# json_encode outputs object instead of array for some elements

Tags: php, json

I have this array and I want to encode it into json..

```
Array
    [0] => Array
        [0] => . Hour
        [1] => bteam_pvp
        [2] => crackpack
        [3] => tppi
        [4] => agrarian_plus
        [5] => agrarian2
        [6] => bteam_pve
        [7] => agrarian
        [8] => horizons
        [9] => m_lobby
        [10] => m_north
        [11] => m_south
        [12] => m_east
        [13] => hub
    [1] => Array
        [0] => 24
        [1] => 91
        [2] => 81
        [3] => 64
        [4] => 98
        [5] => 72
        [6] => 37
        [8] => 63
        [9] => 93
        [10] => 59
        [11] => 92
        [12] => 67
        [13] => 98
```

So I use this:

```php
echo '[';
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo json_encode($row) . ",";
}
echo ']';
```

I get this result:

```json
[
    [". Hour","bteam_pvp","crackpack","tppi","agrarian_plus","agrarian2","bteam_pve","agrarian","horizons","m_lobby","m_north","m_south","m_east","hub"],
    {"0":24,"1":94,"2":96,"4":98,"5":82,"6":69,"8":97,"9":98,"10":96,"11":98,"12":97,"13":99}
]
```

Can you explain me why the last element is encoded as an object instead of an array?

Comment: Your last entry misses index `[3]`, thus is not a plain indexed array.

Comment: Just wondering why you don't just encode the entire array?

Comment: The problem is that arrays (not hashes) in Javascript (and most other languages for that matter) can't have user defined keys.

Comment: @JammyDodger231 I use it in another foor loop with more data that needs it. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to be encoded as an array literal rather than an object, the array *must* be a non-sparse, indexed array.

In your case, your last array is missing `[7]`, making it sparse, and therefore encoded as an object.

Comment: ahh, thanks. Is there a solution for this without modifying the array before?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the last row is the array with assigned keys:

```
{"0":24,"1":94,"2":96,"4":98,"5":82,"6":69,"8":97,"9":98,"10":96,"11":98,"12":97,"13":99}
```

Why? Because you missed key "3", which is in the input you gave, but isn't in json output. Check your input array and keys of last row.

If you don't want to edit your input array, do it like this:

```
[<?php 
foreach ($gPerformance as $row) {
    echo json_encode(array_values($row)) . ",";
}
?>]
```

Comment: thanks for the edit. As I use this data for charts I can't miss one, else it mixes all up. So I have to modify it before and set the one to 0, right?

Comment: That depends. If u need something like this 0 => 20, 1 => null, 2 => 44 then yes, you have to rearrange your input array.